# format a pc with windows xp without losing drivers?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers

I don't know if this question is duplicate or not, but I only find the answer for win7 and I don't know if the same apply to this.

My problem is this: I want to format a old with windows XP because is too slow probably because a virus or something else, and therefore I want format it to start clean again with windows XP, I am not sure if that machine can handle a more modern windows, so I prefer to stay with XP, which is enough for my needs, but my problem is that I lost the disc with the drivers of the motherboar and other stuff that I may need, so my question is:

how can I format my pc with windows XP without losing my drivers??

Comment: There are programs dedicated to backing up drivers, but it seems like a wasted effort, since you can simply download them ahead of time.  What you are asking isn't possible, you can't "format the drive" and keep your drivers unless you back them up first.  **NO** I will not recommend or even mention any program per the site's rules.

Comment: If you have a XP installation disk, you should be able to do a recovery installation, which would wipe out everythign in C:\Windows\system32, but leave your program files and documents alone.

Comment: @j0h yes have the disc of XP

Comment: Read the repair XP section twords the bottom
http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm

Answer (score -1):

If you can't find them, you'll just have to back them up or copy them to some sort of external drive. I would reccomend downloading an antivirus free trial to scan everything so you know the backup won't have any viruses on it.

Also, I'm not sure if a reformat is what you need. Hardrive format doesn't affect speed much at all, if you have a PC or any tech savvy friends a SSD (Solid State Drive) can drastically improve speed for a low price. It can often be a great way to speed up your old computer

Comment: sadly I right now I can't afford any new piece

Comment: then how I can back up those driver?? copying some folder?

Comment: As the site rules I can't really reccomend a specific one, just Google 'driver backups' or 'driver back up maker' and again, reformatting probably isnt the problem, it doesnt affect speed much. The only real fixable thing without buying an SSD is to scan for viruses HHDs are pretty slow, espicially older ones